# Merging asynchronous data and consuming it without race conditions in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have a simple express server listening to POST requests coming in. Each of these 3 possible POST payloads is  parsed into a JSON object (partial). One of the objects acts as a “link table” or “link object” because it contains an ID that can be found in 2nd object and another ID that can be found in 3rd object.

My goal is to connect all these 3 objects and their properties and combine them into one object and push it onto an array.
I wrote a function to find an index of the object in an array that has the property I am looking for in each iteration so I can update existing object on the global array of merged objects or add a new partial object. I call this function every time I get a new partial POST payload object.

```js
 async function findIndexOfElement(array, property, searchParam) {
    return array.findIndex((el) => {
        if (el[property]) {
            return el[property].includes(searchParam);
        } 
    });
}
```

I also have another asynchronous function that is consuming these objects and poping them off an array.
I encountered some sort of race condition because the 3 possible POST payloads do not come always in the same order or at the same time. I didn’t post full code that deals with creating and updating objects because it is too long. I have a bug that causes new partial object to be added as standalone objects, instead being merged by finding the common ID. Possibly the error could even be in `findIndexOfElement` returning wrong index (-1) under some circumstances. I just wish to ask if this is the right design pattern or should I rewrite it differently.

My asynchronous loop is basically:

```js
...
let sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
...
async function downloadLoop() {
    while (true) {
       await sleep(5000);
       ...
    }
}
```

But the await inside the while loop does not seem to be waiting. I added the await to fix (ugly, I know) the unpredictability of the POST data coming in, tp not have it start consuming objects from the array while I wait for all the partial POST payloads to come in.

Comment: Have you looked into RxJS and Observables? This seems like an ideal use case.

Comment: Why doesn't the client send all the data at once? How do you *want* to handle the parts occurring in different orders? It's clear that you don't want to handle anything until the full object is complete, but how do you want to treat repetitions? Timeouts?

Comment: Right now, I check if an object with properties that just arrived already exist on the array and at what index. If it does, I modify existing object, if not I create a new one partial one and add it to array. I solved 1 bug already, turns out the xml file I was parsing with regex does not come in always with properties in the same order, unusual. I have no effect on the order of data that comes in. Right now the program actually works, I just don’t think it is optimal and good. @Noah I will have to look into RxJS as I never worked with it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the "correct" answer for this scenario may seem more complex than you want, but in my experience, it's good to handle these things the "right" way.

#### First, let's reduce the problem

If I have the problem right, then we have three endpoints that may not know about one another, and they need to combine the data from each into a central place. For each set of 3, one type of data links to the other two. And we can't guarantee the order we receive them, but we *do* know that we need 3 data pieces per completed item. I think we solve the problem like so:

1. Store the data in a central location, external to each endpoint handler;
2. Store each piece of data by its unique id;
3. Whenever a piece of data is stored, check the existing data stores;
4. if the data set is complete, push the data set to its final destination and cleanup the data store;

#### A contrived example:

```
// data store

const dataStoreA = {};
const dataStoreB = {};
const dataStoreC = {
  a: {},
  b: {},
};
```

```
// endpoint handlers

function endpointA(data) {
  // store A data types by their id
  dataStoreA[data.id] = data;
  checkForA(data);
}

function endpointB(data) {
  // store B data types by their id
  dataStoreB[data.id] = data;
  checkForB(data);
}

// let's pretend C is the data that links A and B
// let's then store the data from C by it's A and B ids,
// so that A and B can find it later
// this is the key to it all
// you'll see in the data checker functions below
function endpointC(data) {
  dataStoreC.a[data.a_id] = data;
  dataStoreC.b[data.b_id] = data;
  checkForC(data);
}
```

```
// data checkers

function checkForA(a) {
  // first, check C, since C knows about A and B
  const c = dataStoreC.a[a.id];
  let b;

  // now if we have C, we know B as well
  if (c) {
    b = dataStoreB[c.b_id];  
  }

  // if all data was found;
  // pass data on and clean up data stores
  // else we do nothing and wait for more data
  // another handler will pick our data up
  if (b && c) {
    sendDataOnItsMerryWay({ a, b, c });
    cleanupDataStore(a, b);
  }
}

function checkForB(b) {
  // first, check C, since C knows about A and B
  const c = dataStoreC.b[b.id];
  let a;

  // now if we have C, we know A as well
  if (c) {
    a = dataStoreA[c.a_id];  
  }

  // if all data was found;
  // pass data on and clean up data stores
  // else we do nothing and wait for more data
  // another handler will pick our data up
  if (a && c) {
    sendDataOnItsMerryWay({ a, b, c });
    cleanupDataStore(a, b);
  }
}

// checking for c is different since it knows what to look for
function checkForC(c) {
  const a = dataStoreA[c.a_id];
  const b = dataStoreB[c.b_id];

  // if all data was found;
  // pass data on and clean up data stores
  // else we do nothing and wait for more data
  // another handler will pick our data up
  if (a && b) {
    sendDataOnItsMerryWay({ a, b, c });
    cleanupDataStore(a, b);
  }
}

// helpers

function cleanupDataStore(a, b) {
  delete dataStoreA[a.id];
  delete dataStoreB[b.id];
  delete dataStoreC.a[a.id];
  delete dataStoreC.b[b.id];
}
```

There are plenty of ways you can clean this up to make it look/feel better but that's the core concept. No async needed, just a single source of truth required.

#### However

You probably don't want to store this data in memory, because that's not the Cloud Way™, but also for plenty of good reasons. This is what tools like [Redis](https://redis.io/) were made for. You may think an external cache is overkill, but setting up Redis is super-simple and really powerful. When you've setup Redis on your local or connected to a cloud-hosted instance, your code might look like this instead:

```
// data store

const { promisify } = require("util");
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();

// so we can use Promises / Async/Await
const dataStore = {
  get: promisify(client.get).bind(client),
  set: promisify(client.set).bind(client),
};
```

```
// endpoint handlers (using async/await now to handle async actions)

async function endpointA(data) {
  // store A data types by their id
  await dataStore.set(`A_${data.id}`, data);
  await checkForA(data);
}

async function endpointB(data) {
  // store B data types by their id
  await dataStore.set(`B_${data.id}`, data);
  await checkForB(data);
}

// let's pretend C is the data that links A and B
// let's then store the data from C by it's A and B ids,
// so that A and B can find it later
// this is the key to it all
// you'll see in the data checker functions below
async function endpointC(data) {
  await dataStore.set(`C_A_${data.a_id}`, data);
  await dataStore.set(`C_B_${data.b_id}`, data);
  await checkForC(data);
}
```

```
// data checkers

async function checkForA(a) {
  // first, check C, since C knows about A and B
  const c = await dataStore.get(`C_A_${a.id}`);
  let b;

  if (c) {
    b = await dataStore.get(`B_${c.b_id}`);
  }

  // if all data was found;
  // pass data on and clean up data stores
  // else we do nothing and wait for more data
  // another handler will pick our data up
  if (b && c) {
    sendDataOnItsMerryWay({ a, b, c });
    cleanupDataStore(a, b);
  }
}

async function checkForB(b) {
  // first, check C, since C knows about A and B
  const c = await dataStore.get(`C_B_${b.id}`);
  let a;

  if (c) {
    a = await dataStore.get(`A_${c.a_id}`);
  }

  // if all data was found;
  // pass data on and clean up data stores
  // else we do nothing and wait for more data
  // another handler will pick our data up
  if (a && c) {
    sendDataOnItsMerryWay({ a, b, c });
    cleanupDataStore(a, b);
  }
}

// checking for c is different since it knows what to look for
async function checkForC(c) {
  const a = await dataStore.get(`A_${c.a_id}`);
  const b = await dataStore.get(`B_${c.b_id}`);

  // if all data was found;
  // pass data on and clean up data stores
  // else we do nothing and wait for more data
  // another handler will pick our data up
  if (a && b) {
    sendDataOnItsMerryWay({ a, b, c });
    cleanupDataStore(a, b);
  }
}

// helpers

async function cleanupDataStore(a, b) {
  dataStore.del(`A_${a.id}`);
  dataStore.del(`B_${b.id}`);
  dataStore.del(`C_A_${a.id}`);
  dataStore.del(`C_B_${b.id}`);
}
```

You can handle async and use the redis library more efficiently but that's the gist of it.

Comment: Note: when using redis or another external data source with async communication, you do introduce an edge case possibility for completed items to be left behind, at which point you need to run a job periodically to pick up the stragglers.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. You got it down exactly as it is. I think all my issues came from me not wanting to store all incoming data in memory and trying to reinvent the wheel on how to handle it.